# How fix layout checkbox over label in ngx-formly?

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

The control checkbox appears over the label.
This is the control declaration:
[image: Image of the error]

```
{  
   key: 'checked', 
   type: 'checkbox',                    
   templateOptions: {
      label: 'Bollo virtuale',     
      indeterminate: false,                              
   },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap:

```
{  
   key: 'checked', 
   type: 'checkbox',                  
   className: 'inline pr-1',
   templateOptions: {
      label: 'Bollo virtuale',     
      indeterminate: false,                              
   },
}
```